# Wordpress multisite not working

Tags: multisite

I've got a multi-site Wordpress website @ http://angelcard.example.com/logmein

It has domain mapping applied and the domain loads as: http://angelcard.com.au/logmein

On the client's PC http://angelcardreadings.co/logmein loads a blank page.

However, the website loads okay on my PC, but not on my client's PC.

I have tried clearing the browser cache on the client's PC, and another browser as well, but I can't identify what the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How can you have a site at http://angelcard.example.com/logmein?  The address isn't invalid.

For the other link you provided http://angelcard.com.au/logmein DNS does not resolve, at least from my connection.  It also does not resolve from AWS in N. Virginia.

```
/usr/home/bill/> nslookup angelcard.com.au
Server:         216.92.61.41
Address:        216.92.61.41#53

** server can't find angelcard.com.au: NXDOMAIN
```

Were DNS records recently created for angelcard.com.au?  Maybe there just hasn't been enough time for DNS to propagate.

Since it works from your PC I wonder if you have a local hosts file entry?

Check the result of nslookup on your PC and you client's PC

Comment: Hi BillK. example.com is usually used as an example domain.

Comment: Yeah, I know about example.com.  Your angelcard.com.au DNS still doesn't work; that is a problem.

Comment: Apologies. Should be http://angelcardreadings.co/logmein

Comment: The login link, and the front end, are working for me.  Is your client getting the white screen on the logmein page only, or on the front end as well?